# PyDrake: get reaction force and contact results

Tags: drake

In using *plant.get_reaction_forces_output_port()* and *plant.get_contact_results_output_port()*, the output have structures *SpatialForce* and *ContactResults*. In the c++ implementation, the data structure can be directly specified as *vector>*. How do I do the same in PyDrake? Particularly when 1) accessing the raw values of *&tau* and *&f*, and 2) feeding into a data logger such as *LogOutput()*

Comment: I think I figured it out: DeclareAbstractInput/OutputPort("name", AbstractValue.Make(ContactResults()))

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but yes, that should be the right thing!